# Changing an @Input component object isn't reflected in parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() childObject: ChildObject;

    changeObject(newObject: ChildObject){
        childObject = newObject;
    }
}
```

When I call `changeObject`, my `ChildComponent` reflect the changes, but my `ParentComponent`, which contains the `ChildComponent`, isn't updated with this change.

I.e.: If, in my `ParentComponent` template I have something like `{{parent.childObject.name}}`, this value stay unchanged.

I tried to use `childObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newObject));` but it doesn't help.
I guess it's a problem of object reference changing, so I added a method `copy(newObject: ChildObject)` that makes a copy property-by-property in my `ChildObject` class, but when I call it in my `changeObject` method, I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: _this.childObject.copy is not a function.

**Update: ChildObject class**

```
export class ChildObject {
  constructor(
    public name: string // , ...
  ) { }

  copy(childObject: ChildObject) {
    this.name = childObject.name;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to emit the changes back to parent - `@Input()` properties doesn't carry the reference

Comment: `@input` works the other way try `@output` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
A direct assignment will not work because it replaces original object reference with the new one

```
this.childObject = newObject; // Will not work
```

However, any update on an existing object should work

```
this.childObject.someProperty = newObject; // should work

Object.assign(this.childObject, newObject);  // should work since it will assign the merge to the first object
```

---

Should work since objects are passed as a reference while passing inputs. The only problem I see in the code you have posted is you should refer to the childObject as this.childObject

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'child'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() childObject: ChildObject;

    changeObject(newObject: ChildObject){
        this.childObject = newObject;
    }
}
```

This should work. Although I would not do it this way. This can be done in a cleaner way.

Comment: I just forgot `this` while typing my exemple, but it is in place in my accual code and no it doesn't work. Why do you think it isn't a clean way? It looks to me quite simple and maintainable.

Comment: '@Input' should be used to pass data from parent to child and not the other way around. If you want to pass data from child to parent component, you should use '@Output', ValueAccessor or service. I do not recommend using service as well but it's an option.

Comment: Well, this is only model data for my form, so the changes are always sent back to the parent components. The reason why i have this object copy is that the user can select the ChildObject in a list to auto-complete the  form.

Comment: Yes, this works. Simple and clean (I guess). Do you know what `Object.assign` does to refererences type (i.e., if I have other complex objects in `ChildObject`)? Are the object references copied to the object or is it a recursive copy?

Comment: It's a recursive copy. If I have 2 objects `obj1` and `obj2` and I do `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`, it will copy all properties from `obj2` to `obj1` and these copied properties will no longer have reference to `obj2`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Yes, but what about `obj1.obj11.obj1111`?

Comment: If `obj2.obj11.obj1111` exists then it will overwrite `obj1.obj11.obj1111`

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I seem to face: if `obj2.obj11` is undefined, `obj1.obj11` stays unchanged.

Comment: Yes, if a property is undefined in `obj2`, that property in `obj1` will remain unchanged. If you HAVE to, you can initialize the properties in obj2 will `null` value. I cannot think of anything else at the moment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I will do. Even if I see a really annoying problem: if the class definition changes over time, I have to remember to update the initialize method. _I won't_

Answer (score 2):

this will not work, you should use here `service` or `@Output`, I would suggest to use `@Output` here if there will be only this communication between your components

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() childObject: ChildObject;
    @Output() onChildObjectChange = new EventEmitter<ChildObject>();
    changeObject(newObject: ChildObject){
        childObject = newObject;
        this.onChildObjectChange.emit(newObject);
    }
}
```

**Parent component**
**Html**

```
<child (onChildObjectChange)="updateObject($event)"></child>
```

**ts**

```
updateObject(newObject: ChildObject) {
  childObject = newObject
}
```

Comment: Hum... seems _quite complex_ for something that should be automatic. In that case, I'd rather investigate my `copy(newObject: ChildObject)` solution in the `ChildObject` class that makes a property by property update. But I can't make out why I get this `not a function` error...

Comment: @Sébastien this is one of possible solutions, you can also use services, also can you provide code where you are getting `not a function` error so we can help in that case too

Comment: My `ChildObject` class is a quite simple model class, I updated my question with this class.

Comment: @sebastian when you are passing childObject from parent to child does it has the copy method? I would suggest to use services instead of that class

Comment: Isn't the method set at class level?

Comment: @Sébastien no it only says that your object should be of the type of that class, but it doesn't contain that method automatically

Comment: Well, my object is created by the `HttpClient.request` method with the type parameter (generic attribute) set to `ChildObject`. I don't know if it includes the class methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can possiable get the value changed by adding `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on your child

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() childObject: ChildObject;

    changeObject(newObject: ChildObject){
        childObject = newObject;
    }
}
```

This will update your object whenever there is any event triggering on your child `component` the case is that both the child component and parent component `changeDetection` will occur and thus it will update your object

Hope you're expecting something like this - Happy coding !!

Comment: Some event should be triggered to achieve this - if not change it to default `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` which will trigger every time without event change